# Scalafx on Android

Tags: android, scalafx, javafxports

Is it possible to build and run ScalaFX applications on Android?

I'm aware of cross-build of JavaFX supported by [gluon](http://gluonhq.com/open-source/javafxports/). Can ScalaFX be combined with this, or by other means? What are the intricacies? Among other things:

- How does building work, as I understand that currently it uses Gradle - can this be replaced with SBT?
- Also, I believe that most Scala applications that are run on Android need to be stripped of unused library code, otherwise they binaries are really large. Is that right?

Any other steps that need to be taken into account?

Comment: Have you successfully used ScalaFX for an Android Application ? I'm searching exactly the same thing

Comment: No, I've had to put this on hold, but will try to remember to update the answer here once I get around to it. I do think this is doable.

Answer (score 1):

There is already an application that combines Scala and JavaFXPorts:

Code: 
https://github.com/rladstaetter/fx-tictactoe

Blog posts:

- http://ladstatt.blogspot.com.es/2016/01/fx-tictactoe-tictactoe-javafx.html
- http://ladstatt.blogspot.com.es/2016/02/fx-tictactoe-deploy-javafx-app-into.html

And you can actually download from [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.ladstatt.tictactoe) and test it.

Comment: This is quite useful, but it's JavaFX + Scala, which is not exactly the same as www.scalafx.org. Also this project uses Gradle, rather than SBT. What I'm looking is to use part of the 'native' scala eosystem (i.e. SBT and ScalaFX), rather than just scala as 'glue'. I'll try the instructions from http://macroid.github.io/ScalaOnAndroid.html and try and combine it with your sample here ...

Comment: While I'm not a Scala expert, I think ScalaFX should work, but SBT won't work with JavaFXPorts, since all its build chain is based on Gradle.